# Angularjs change url without changing the state, when ui bootstrap modal is opened. Revert url to previous state when modal is closed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-modal

I am trying to implement Pinterest style listing page, where on click of pins the details popup opens up and the url changes to something like http://pinterest.com/pin/123456. But the page is intact behind. When the popup is closed, the page behind is still there.

I have checked the similar feature of history api to change url of the browser without refreshing the page using "pushState" feature.

I want to implement the same in Angular but as soon as the browser's url is changed via pushState, the background page is reloaded due to the default "state change" event.

Any ideas are appreciated?

Comment: Did you try making the UI Bootstrap modal state child of the main page state?

Comment: @RahulArora I already have a state for the url. May be if you go to pinterest's home page and click any of the pins you will have a better idea.

Comment: Is that state a child of the main page state from where the modal triggers?

Answer (score 0):

Make the modal state child of the main state,

In this case the main page will remain intact and the modal being the child of that state will trigger with new URL without actually refreshing the background.